# What mathematical models did Harry Markopolos run to prove that Bernie Madoff 1% a month gain was a Ponzi scheme?

Tags: quant-trading-strategies, backtesting, option-strategies

http://www.cbsnews.com/news/the-man-who-figured-out-madoffs-scheme-27-02-2009/

> Asked how long it took him to figure out something was wrong,
>   Markopolos said, "It took me five minutes to know that it was a fraud.
>   It took me another almost four hours of mathematical modeling to prove
>   that it was a fraud. "

Comment: I think they used factor models which showed that no reasonable combination of assets could achieve such returns.

Comment: The Sharp ratio was a useful tool. "The quantitative analysis Markopolos conducted, showing that over 96% of monthly returns were positive; correlation with the stock market was negligible at around 6%; and the Sharpe ratio was outsize, ranging between 2.5 and 4.0 for most time frames, was literally unbelievable." [Source](https://www.morningstar.in/posts/72652/the-madoff-netflix-special-lessons-for-investors.aspx)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can find everything you want to know about this here (and in a very readable and easily reproducible form):

[How Students Can Backtest Madoff’s Claims by Michael J. Stutzer (2009)](http://oldleeds.colorado.edu/asset/burridge/backtestmadoffsclaims.pdf)

From the abstract:

> Markopolos’ writings neither described nor included any specific
>   backtests of the strike conversion strategy. Fortunately, a backtest
>   is relatively easy to implement, using just a few, free data series
>   found online, a single spreadsheet, and the Black-Scholes formula. I
>   developed a disguised, simplified backtest as a home assignment for
>   undergrads students, and extended it into a longer, more realistic
>   paper assignment for another student. Based on those experiences, I
>   describe herein a suitable backtest methodology and questions that may
>   be answered through it.